# Creating a list of sums

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm newbie in Python and I'm struggling in create a list of sums generated by a for loop.

I got an school assignment where my program have to simulate the scores of a class of blind students in a multiple choice test.

```
def blindwalk():       # Generates the blind answers in a test with 21 questions
    import random
    resp = []
    gab = ["a","b","c","d"]
    for n in range(0,21):
        resp.append(random.choice(gab))
    return(resp)

def gabarite():        # Generates the official answer key of the tests
    import random
    answ_gab = []
    gab = ["a","b","c","d"]
    for n in range(0,21):
        answ_gab.append(random.choice(gab))
    return(answ_gab)

def class_tests(A):    # A is the number of students
    alumni = []
    A = int(A)
    for a in range(0,A):
        alumni.append(blindwalk())
    return alumni

def class_total(A):    # A is the number of students
    A = int(A)
    official_gab = gabarite()
    tests = class_tests(A)
    total_score = []*0
    for a in range(0,A):
        for n in range(0,21):
            if  tests[a][n] == official_gab[n]:
                total_score[a].add(1)
    return total_score
```

When I run the class_total() function, I get this error:

```
    total_score[a].add(1)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Question is: How I valuate the scores of each student and create a list with them, because this is what I want to do with the class_total() function.

I also tried

```
if  tests[a][n] == official_gab[n]:
                    total_score[a] += 1
```

But I got the same error, so I think I don't fully understand how lists work in Python yet.

Thanks!

(Also, I'm not a English native-speaker, so please tell me if I couldn't be clear enough)

Comment: Did you mean `total_score = [] * A`?

Comment: No, the error is referring to line 39, which is `total_score[a].add(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
total_score = []*0
```

And in fact, any of the following lines:

```
total_score = []*30
total_score = []*3000
total_score = []*300000000
```

Cause total_score to be instantiated as an empty list.  It doesn't even have a 0th index, in this case!  If you'd like to initiate every value to x in a list of length l , the syntax would look more like:

```
my_list = [x]*l
```

Alternatively, instead of thinking about the size before-hand, you can use .append instead of trying to access a particular index, as in:

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(200)
# my_list is now [200], my_list[0] is now 200
my_list.append(300)
# my_list is now [200,300], my_list[0] is still 200 and my_list[1] is now 300
```

Comment: I used this because I had to initialize this list. So I thought that if I created a list of zeros, I could sum/add the answers of each student directly in the list to obtain his score (something like  0+1+1+1+0+1+0+0... = score of one student) instead calculating each student score and then appending it to the list.

Using my_list = [] still gives me the same error:

`total_score[a].add(1)`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Is that possible what I'm trying to do? I mean, I can iteratively sum one item in a list or I have to do the sum before and then placing it in the list?

Comment: I just use the `my_list = [0]*A` method. I understand now what you meant: my list didn't have any indexes. Now, I created a list of zeros with length = "A" (number of students) and worked. Many thanks!

Comment: i tried, but I don't have rep enough to upvote your answer. It seems I need at least 15 of reputation for that. EDIT: Done =P